# what is the best way to parse a file which is not pure xml in python

Tags: python

i am trying to parse a file in python which is not pure xml, since its not purly xml, xml parser fails to parse the file.

please suggest me a solution to this , i dont want to read the file with I/O functions.

```
<groups>
   <url>
      description = helloz
      <whatis>
         <what_is_that>
            active = yes
            <inside_what>
               <default>
                  <0>
                     tagid = 0

                  </0>
               </default>
            </inside_what>
            <second_list>
               <0>
                  name = do
               </0>
            </second_list>
         </what_is_that>
```

Comment: Corrected the closing `inside_what` tag. It was missing `/`

Comment: Judging by the structure, I sure say that you must go with JSON rather than XML. What you have here is pure JSON but tried to be represented as XML.

Comment: i tried to read like json file ,but it does n't seems to be purely json either

Comment: data = []
with codecs.open('C:\Users\a\Desktop\Automation work\abc.cfg','rU','utf-8')as data_file:
 for line in data_file:
         data.append(json.loads(line))

Comment: i tried to read the data as json , but it does n't seems to be a complete json file either . giving me errror Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
>>>

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with BeautifulSoup. When you make a BeautifulSoup object it will insert the missing closing tags by itself. And then you are good to go and extract anything you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('file_name', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(a, 'lxml')
    print soup.find('inside_what')
```

Output:

```
<inside_what>
<default>

                     tagid = 0

                  0&gt;
               </default>
</inside_what>
```

Comment: the file is quite large and i am not sure how many closing tag is missing, going by this i manually have to find about them, which is time consuming

Comment: @pankajmishra You don't have to find the missing closing tags manually. BeautifulSoup will close it for you.

Comment: with open('C:\Users\pankaj-m\Desktop\Automation work\sqlserver_monitor.cfg', 'r') as f:
 a = f.read()
     soup=BeautifulSoup(a, 'lxml')
     print soup.find('groups')

Comment: its giving me error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requeste
d: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library? ....  i have installed Ixml//python 2.7 i am using